# Lagranges method of solving Partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

After solving the differential equation $xp + yq = z$ using this method we get the general solution as $f(x/y,y/z)=0$
But substituting $f(x/y,y/z)$ in the place of $z$ in differential equation gives us terms like $q$ on substituting. Here we cannot replace $q$ since it will bring us back to the same state with $q$ in the expression in spite of the substitution... My question is how do we confirm that $f(x/y,y/z)$ is the solution of the given differential equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z(x,y) \tag 1$$
You correctly found this form of implicit solution :
$$f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}\right)=0 \tag 2$$
Since $f$ is an arbitrary function, they are many equivalent forms of implicit equations, such as for example $g\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{z}{y}\right)=0$ , or $h\left(\frac{y}{z},\frac{z}{x}\right)=0$ , etc.

with arbitrary functions $g,h,$ etc.

Or on equivalent explicit form :
$$\frac{y}{z}=F\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\quad\implies\quad z(x,y)=y\frac{1}{F\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}$$

or equivalently 
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=y\:\Phi\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}\tag 3$$
$F$ and $\Phi$ are arbitrary functions.

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{y}\Phi'\quad$ and $\quad\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\Phi-\frac{x}{y^2}\Phi'$
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x\left(\frac{1}{y}\Phi' \right)+y\left(\Phi-\frac{x}{y^2}\Phi' \right)$$
After simplification :
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=y\:\Phi$$
Thus 
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z$$
This confirms that $(3)$ is solution of the PDE $(1)$.

Of course it is possible to directly confirm that $(2)$ is solution of the PDE $(1)$ : One have to express the total differential of $(2)$ with respect to $dx,dy,dz$. and further calculus confirms that $(1)$ is satisfied.

ADDITION to answer to Denis James's comment :

$$f\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}\right)=0 \tag 2$$
$$f(X,Y)=0\quad
\begin{cases}
X=\frac{x}{y} \quad\implies\quad dX=\frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy\\
Y=\frac{y}{z} \quad\implies\quad dY=\frac{1}{z}dy-\frac{y}{z^2}dz
\end{cases}$$

$$df=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\left(\frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy\right)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\left(\frac{1}{z}dy-\frac{y}{z^2}dz\right) $$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}dz=\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{1}{y}dx
+\left(-\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{x}{y^2}
+\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{1}{z}\right)dy$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}} \quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{1}{z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}}$$

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}} +y \frac{-\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{x}{y^2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{1}{z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}}$$
$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=y  \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{1}{z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{y}{z^2}}=z$$
Equation $(1)$ is satisfied which proves that $(2)$ is solution of the PDE.

Of course, the solution expressed on the form of implicit equation $(2)$ is not the best manner to express the solution. The equivalent explicit form $(3)$ is much simpler for further use, especially if some boundary condition was specified.

Comment: i tried my best to manipulate the total differential of $(2)$  to arrive at the equation but I couldnt. I would be grateful to you if you give me the solution to this problem since i have been trying this question for about a mounth now which i think is too much @JJacquelin

Comment: See the addition to my main answer.

Answer (score 0):

Making the change of coordinates

$$
\cases{
\xi = x\\
\eta = \frac xy
}
$$

we have $z(x,y) = u(\xi,\eta)$ and

$$
u(\xi,\eta) = \xi u_{\xi}(\xi,\eta)
$$

this PDE is solved like a separable ODE giving

$$
u(\xi,\eta) = \xi\Phi(\eta)
$$

or

$$
z(x,y) = x\Phi\left(\frac xy\right)
$$